# Nagios does not send the graph in email

Tags: email, nagios, graphite

So, I have been trying to make Nagios work with Graphite to send alert emails but that's not working right. I used the following URL to set everything up:

http://www.protocolostomy.com/2012/02/24/sending-alerts-with-graphite-graphs-from-nagios/

The sendgraph.py alone, with the correct parameters sends a correct email with the graph properly displayed. But if I use nagios to send the graph it sends the correct message but the graph does not show up. I only get a file name which when tried to open gives me this message: "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize." I have no idea why. All the work of sending the graph is done by sendgraph.py and it has all the correct parameters to it for sure because the URL gives the correct values from Graphite and then I get the email (so the email is correct) and I get the description and state of the graph correctly.

Could anyone please suggest me a way out of this?

Thanks!

Comment: So, I have noticed that nagios strips off the '&' of the URL and hence this problem! Looking for a way to preserve the '&'. I will update this if I find one. Until then if someone knows the way out, please comment. :) It's killing me!

Answer (score 0):

In the Nagios documentation for [macros](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macros.html) it states:

"Additionally, any macros that contain custom variables are stripped for safety and security."

In you nagios.cfg file, try removing the '&' from this line:

```
illegal_macro_output_chars=`~$^&"|'<>
```

Comment: @josecarlow, After removal, did you bounce the Nagios process?